# GitHub Actions and AWS RDS connect and build error

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions, amazon-rds

I tried to use GitHub Actions, but ran into these errors:

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

I want to connect GitHub Action runner to my AWS RDS instance.

Here's my workflow (`gradle.yaml`):

```yaml
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.
# This workflow will build a Java project with Gradle and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-gradle

name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        
    - name: Setup MySQL
      uses: samin/mysql-action@v1
      with:
        mysql host: ${{ secrets.RDS_END_POINT }}
        mysql port: 3306
        mysql database: db name
        mysql user: user name
        mysql password: ${{ secrets.MY_SQL_PASSWORD }}
        
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
      with:
        arguments: build
```

I wrote RDS endpoint, port, db name, my aws account, password. But build failed:

```java
myapplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
            Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException at AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:284
                Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException at DialectFactoryImpl.java:100
```

I need your help. Thanks!

I tried to add MySQL DB setup to my `gradle.yaml` file but it didn't work either.

Comment: That action sets up a local MySQL server. That is completely unnecessary as it is [preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#mysql). But, you're trying to connect to the AWS RDS instance and not a local DB. You don't need to do set up a local instance. Simply, add creds to secrets (as you're already doing), populates env vars, in your code fetch those values from env vars and connect.

Comment: @Azeem thanks. my project contains connection to rds. so, that set-up unnecessary. i have to check rds inbound rule. Could the rds inbound rule for the github runner be a problem?

Comment: Isn't your app the one initiating a connection to RDS?